# How to get Powerpoint to autofit text

Tags: python, powerpoint

Is it possible to get Powerpoint 2013 to autofit text properly?  I'm using python-pptx and I can set the option to autofit, but it doesn't work initially.  If I resize the text box or subsequently change a setting like "wrap" then the auto fitting works.  However, I can't do that from python-pptx.  I need the option to work the first time I add text.

I presume this is a bug in PowerPoint that Microsoft don't intend to fix, but hopefully I'm wrong.

Comment: As a workaround, I can hide every slide in the presentation and then show it again, using a VB macros.  This fixes the problem, but it would be nice not to have to do this.

Comment: You should post that as your own answer I guess. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple code that will wrap a text within a text frame without a need to resize the textbox. I hope this helps.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

prs = Presentation()
titleLayout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(titleLayout)

textBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(Inches(3.5), Inches(0.5),Inches(3), Inches(3.0))
textFrame = textBox.text_frame
textFrame.word_wrap = True
textParagraph = textFrame.add_paragraph()
textParagraph.text = "This is a word_wrap example. The words  are wrapped within the textframe"

prs.save("C:\OSGeo4W\GPSPictureManager\Tests\PptxWordWrapTest.pptx")#specify path for new pptx file
```

More details can be found in http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#textframe-objects